# Why does node_modules folder become corrupt upon Visual Studio publish AspNetCore2 project?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core, kendo-angular-ui

I have been developing an AspNetCore project using Kendo, Angular5, and AspNet Mvc. Everything has been going fine during development but I am running into a weird circumstance where when I try to publish my project is breaking.

[image: This is my project structure]

Next is my node_modules folder for angular

[image]

When I try to publish I get an error during **npm install** which is part of the process.

---

### Publish failed

Publish has encountered an error.
Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE3BC.tmp"

That file contains a very non descriptive stacktrace with the following exception

---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---

Also the output window has the npm error:

Could not resolve @progress/kendo-angular-l10n relative to C:/Projects/API/Main/angular/ClientApp/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.d.ts..[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31mnode_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/filtering/operators/filter-operator.base.d.ts(1,37): Error TS2307: Cannot find module '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n'.[39m[22m[0m

Okay so something is wrong with the npm install I guess. However, after I try to run my project I get the following error "Cannot Get /" and I can't even run my project anymore. Everything seems broken.

[image]

After poking around for a while and pulling my hair out I noticed the folders where npm install was complaining seem corrupted. I figured this out by trying to open the folder, which now has a little shortcut arrow on it, and I am greeted with the following error message:

[image]

I can get the application to work again by deleting the corrupted folder by I still am unable to publish the applicaition properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out or removing your package-lock.json before publishing.